# How to validate a form using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the  following code ..currently its validating but its not displaying error messages one by one i want to display all the error messages at once ...plz help me thanks in advance

```
if ( $('#employeeid').length > 0 ) {
            if ( $('#employeeid').val() || $('#employeeid').val() == '' ) {
                if( ! $('#employeeid').val().match(/^[I]{1}[BH]{1}[0-9]{1,4}$/i) ) {
                    $('#employeeid-element').append('<ul class="errors"><li><ul class="errors"><li>Please enter a valid employee id</li></ul>');
                      return false;
                  }
              }
          }



   if ( $("#firstname").val() || $("#firstname").val() == '') {
                if( ! $('#firstname').val().match(/^[a-z]{0,10}[\s]{0,2}[a-z]{0,10}$/i) ) {
                        $('#firstname-element').append('<ul class="errors"><li>Please enter a employee first name: firstname</li></ul>');
                        return false;
                    }

            }
```

Comment: -1: Google is your friend: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ - this is the very first result returned. It's trusted enough to be included by Microsoft into new MVC projects.

Answer (score 1):

[**http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Maybe this plugin will help you to do that in a easy way.